# How To Reduce Backlog In Celery Queue Connected To Redis?

Tags: python, redis, celery

I'm using a dockerized celery 4.2 with Redis as a broker and backend, processing data from a Twitter stream.

Sometimes there are interruptions which cause tasks piling up in the queue. Even with sufficient processing power (memory/CPU), celery seems to be unable to reduce this backlog over time after interruptions are fixed and the service is restarted.

Are there any options to change this behaviour in Celery?

Is the likely reason for this behavior  a bottleneck in IO (e.g. read/write to Redis?).

Happy for any kind of input!

Comment: Typical solution (that is why Celery exists) is to add more workers to your Celery cluster...

Comment: Thanks Dejan, I currently run the set up on a single machine with 8 cores, one worker and concurrency of 20. I read that having multiple workers on a single machine makes only sense if they have different queues/purposes. If you think adding more workers might still help, I will try it out.

Comment: You are right - I should have been more precise - I was thinking about adding more physical nodes (one worker with 20 worker processes per machine).

Comment: If your tasks are mostly IO, then add more worker processes... You should monitor that machine and see if that could help. Or, alternatively, change the concurrency type to gevent.

Comment: @DejanLekic Do you guys manage make it working by increasing concurrency more than 1 via Python code configuration? My end seems to be always 1 concurrency despite trying to set concurrency = 5 in Python file.